# Command bin/sh failed with exit code 1 Unrecognized arguments:

Tags: ios, xcode, carthage

This is screen shot of run script

[image: this is screen shot of run script]

I am trying to archive the project, i am getting an error "Command bin/sh failed with exit code 1", but it is working on simulator and device

> Unrecognized arguments: "/Users/macbookpro/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RuleDemo-bhlsqxvcvoalgyecxruhhzlqpmmp/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/RuleDemo/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/RuleDemo.build/Release-iphoneos/RuleDemo.build/Script-52FE86C320B541F900CA5756.sh"
>   Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1

Comment: That looks like a run script issue; please post any run scripts you have from your project.

Comment: i added the image

Comment: That's definitely a Carthage issue; when was the last time you updated it?

Comment: day before yesterday

Comment: do i need to update it again?

Comment: Not necessarily; question - does your project have an Info.plist?

Comment: yes it have an info.plist

Comment: Apparently that error happens when there is none. It looks like your command is correct, so I would suggest adding another Run Script which includes `/usr/local/bin/carthage outdated --xcode-warnings`.

Comment: ok il try with this script

Comment: Also, try unchecking "Run script only when installing".

Comment: It got complied thank u

Comment: the  "Run script only when installing" should be uncecked?

Comment: I usually leave it unchecked, that way it runs the script every time, rather then just when installing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem with the Carthage Run Script. It can usually be resolved by adding another Run Script to  Build Phases:

```
/usr/local/bin/carthage outdated --xcode-warnings
```

Place this Run Script before the others; This script should automatically warn you when one of your dependencies is out of date.

Another thing that I might help is to **uncheck** "Run script only when installing".